# How can I make the live serve to be faster?

Tags: angular, angular-cli-v6

After upgrading to Angular 6, the ng serve in watch mode is very slow. Here is how I am running it locally

```
ng serve --c=dev --watch
```

It is taking forever to build and serve simple changes in single files. It is as if it is doing a regular `ng build --prod`

Did anyone face this issue? Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: how does `ng serve` work for you?

Comment: `-c-dev` should be `-c dev`, surely? Also `--watch` is the default for serving.

Comment: Are you on linux?

Comment: I am on Windows. `ng serve` without `--watch` is same , as it is default. I need the `--c` param for configuration

Comment: maybe your HDD is dying. `ng serve` works more or less fine. If module is large then it can choke for like 3-6 seconds, but later builds are quicker. Also check RAM and CPU

Comment: I have pretty good machine and was not an issue before angular 6

Answer (score 3):

When Angular builds the JavaScript files, you can see that it simultaneously creates their source map files.

###### For example:

```
stlye.js — — style.js.map — — 3.44 MB
vendor.js — — vendor.js.map — — 8.05 MB
main.js — — main.js.map — — 3.68 MB
pages-admin-question-admin-question-module.js — — pages-admin-question-admin-question-module.js.map — — 426 kB*
```

When you do `ng serve`, Angular serves the app from memory instead of the `dist` folder (the file-system). This means the entire code (along with map files) will be loaded into the system's memory and this is the main reason why your system or IDE is getting slow.

> How can I turn off the source map generation while in development?

Well, to turn it off via command, run `ng serve --sourceMap=false` or `ng serve --source-map=false`.
**For Ionic applications** run `ionic serve --source-map=false`.

Comment: --source-map and --sourceMap flags deprecated for me and I'm using angular 15.

Answer (score 1):

I figured this is due to the configuration. Mostly I use `--c=local` which is fast enough but for troubleshooting I needed to use the dev environement configuration after upgrading

```
            "local": {
          "fileReplacements": [
            {
              "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
              "with": "src/environments/environment.local.ts"
            }
          ]
        },
        "dev": {
          "optimization": true,
          "outputHashing": "all",
          "sourceMap": false,
          "extractCss": true,
          "namedChunks": false,
          "aot": true,
          "extractLicenses": true,
          "vendorChunk": false,
          "buildOptimizer": true,
          "fileReplacements": [
            {
              "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
              "with": "src/environments/environment.dev.ts"
            }
          ]
        },
```

Comment: could you tell which file are you editing? it could be useful for someone

Comment: @parmigiana angular.json

Comment: I would argue that `vendorChunk` set to `true` actually make incremental builds faster.